# How to set scrollbar initial position at right end in wx.Listbox using wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, wxpython

I am using the Listbox Widget to display a list of files uploaded by the users and `wx.HSCROLL` style is used. When the string of file names are wider than the size of the listbox, horizontal scrollbar appears as expected. However, I am having trouble in setting the scrollbar auto-rolling to the right end using SetScrollPos method. The following command was used:

```
self.dropfile_listBox.SetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL,self.dropfile_listBox.GetScrollRange(wx.HORIZONTAL))
```

But apparently it did not set the scrollbar position correctly. Any comments about this issue are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you are using `UltimateListCrtl` from your posted code
try:

```
self.dropfile_listBox.SetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL,self.dropfile_listBox.GetScrollRange(wx.HORIZONTAL),refresh=True)
```

which redraws the scroll bar